# Ubuntu Server Static IP Problem

Tags: networking, server, dhcp

Hi I've been trying and trying to chang emy ubuntu servers IP to static so I can have people join my Minecraft server that I have set up, I've been working on it for 2 days straight with no luck, when I change my ip through
 sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces
I was told to change it to something similiar to this
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.100
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1

but it doesnt work for me i have tried in gateway putting my routers Ip address which i found in the routers menu information that doesnt seem to work
what does is when i have the ip as 10.0.0.8 or something similiar thoe i still have problems
can anyone help I relaly want to get this set up and learn how to do this properly?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set your DNS servers manually too.  Example:

vi /etc/resolv.conf

Add the lines (based on opendns):

```
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
```

restart your networking:

```
service networking restart
```

Double check your IP, Netmask and gateway.  They look ok on the surface but make sure nothing else on the network is using 192.168.1.100.

The section in your interfaces file should look similar to:

```
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.100
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
```

More information here:
[Set a static IP on Ubuntu](http://www.howtoforge.com/linux-basics-set-a-static-ip-on-ubuntu)

Dont forget to restart your networking after every change!

Answer (score 0):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

Change:

```
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

To

```
iface eth0 inet static
```

And add the following:

- address 10.0.1.100 (Ubuntu Server IP address)
- netmask 255.255.255.0
- gateway 10.0.1.1
- network 10.0.1.0
- broadcast 10.0.1.255
- dns-nameservers 10.0.1.1

You can also use Google’s Public DNS which is 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4 for dns-nameservers.

Once done, restart networking

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```